# Need some help understanding NextJS re-rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on my first NextS app and have found some things I think are odd. The app is meant to be the front-end of a headless ecommerce system. Currently I have a few pages:

- home
- category
- product

I noticed the other day that if I'm on a product page and I click to go to the home page, the product page component runs again while the browser is loading the home page. I thought I must have a `useEffect` in the product page component causing trouble, so I stripped it down:

```
const Product = props => {
   console.log("PRODUCT PAGE");
   return (
      <div>product</div>
   );
};
export default Product;
```

Even with this minimal code, the console.log is triggered when I navigate to the home page. How / why is that? Is there a way to stop it?

The problem is that my product page appears to be entirely re-rendering (invisibly behind the scenes) when I change routes, and things that should only happen on the product page are now happening on the homepage. For example some third-party scripts that belong on the product page are being added to the DOM again. Note that this happens on clicks to category pages as well, the homepage is just an example.

Second question - I also noticed that things I wouldn't have expected to re-render on every page change are in fact re-rendering a lot. For example the header / leftnav each re-render on route change, even though their state did not change (console.logs in each of these are being triggered). I also notice that they're rendering multiple times instead of just once. Is this normal, or did I screw something up in _app.js somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bogdan-74inp -- Please add a MRE.

Comment: I see that.. hmm it means there must be something with my particular setup. I'll do some slimming down to see if I can A) come up with a better code sample to post here, and B) possibly find the problem myself. Right now there's a ton of code to wade through so posting it all here would be asking a lot of everyone on SO :)

Comment: Found the problem! It was a `useEffect` in `_app.js` with dependency list `[]`. I had a flag (as a piece of state) set to true/false while route change was taking place, so I could fade out the current component and then fade in the new one. So since the state of `_app.js` was changing on route change, lots of annoying stuff was happening. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!